# Refering to columns of a dataframe that have almost the same name inside a loop in r

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I am just a beginner in R and I am working with the following very simple setting. My data-frame has 10 variables labeled as x.1,x.2,...,x.10, and 100 observations.

I need to run a loop over these variables and observations like this

```
   T<- 10
   N <- 100 
for(j in 1:T){
for(i in 1:N){
df1$x.j[*some condition over i*] = def2$y[*some condition over i*]
}
}
```

The only thing I need to know is how to make R understand that when `j = 2` (say) in this loop, `df1$x.j = df1$x.2` and so on until `T=10`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and your data. You could paste dput(your_dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to generate column names

1. Using `grep` to find relevant columns

`cols <- grep("^x\\.", names(col), value = TRUE)`

2. Generating columns by using `paste`

`cols <- paste("x", 1:10, sep = ".")`

Once you get the column names, you can access the particular column using `df[[colname]]`. You can index a particular observation by `df[[colname]][observation_index]`.